# how to create the heading numbers in topic heading in every html file? DTA OT XHTML

Tags: html, xslt, output, tableofcontents, dita

I have tried to insert topic level numbers for topic heading in dita2xhtml_eclipsehelp.xsl. (DITA OT HTML output)

But not able to generate numbers like below in every html file:

```
1 heading text
1.1 heading text
1.1.1 Heading text
2 Heading text
2.1 text
```

Comment: What kind of XSLT code did you try?

Comment: dita2xhtml_eclipsehelp.xsl  (DITA-OT-HTML HELP)            <xsl:number count="*[contains(@class, ' topic/title ')][parent::*[contains(@class,' topic/topic ')]]" level="multiple"/>

Answer (score 1):

The DITA Open Toolkit processes each individual DITA topic to HTML. So the XSLT which processes each topic does not know of the hierarchy of the topic in the DITA Map. You probably need to try and pass as a parameter to the stylesheet the path to the DITA Map and then from the stylesheet use the document() XSLT function to load the DITA Map and look inside it to see in which hierarchy level the current topic is placed. But I cannot give you a precise XSLT code to achieve what you want. Something like my advice for the DITA to HTML5 output: https://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/post67095.html#p67095

Comment: Thank you. I have tried to create topic id attribute for toc.xml and then match with merged xml file for topic heading id and replace the value attribute from toc.xml. Again not working. Please share me the code if any.   <topic label="1.1  heading text" href="GUID-00D008E2-B7C6-430A-8783-252D6BCD90FA.html" id="uniq1"/> uniq1 is the topic heading level id.

Comment: DITA OT - HTML - add heading labels in topic.
I have tried to replace from topic heading (TOC.xml ) into body matter topic header using uniq GUID.
But, TOC.xml is generated after the HTML files in the transformation. Hence, I am not able to open TOC.xml within the XSL.

Please provide any code related to this topic